# Float in a <div> tag or <img>

Tags: html, image

I am not new to HTML or CSS (but I can't claim to be an expert either) and for the life of me what seems to be a simple "Float" in a div tag has completely perplexed me.

I assumed a simple:

```
<div style="float: left;"><img src="....>Text Text text<br>Text Text Text</div>
```

Would place my image on the left and by default start wrapping my text on the right starting at the top right of the image but instead the wording is starting at the lower right of the image and wrapping underneath. Given this is my first post I am unable to insert screenshots but I can send them along if needed.

I have done the code in the following manner given I have a stylesheet but I tried applying the style in the HTML as well (as per the above example) with the same result:

```
CSS
.img-float-left{float:left;}

HTML
<div class="img-float-left"><img src="....>Text Text text<br>Text Text Text</div>
```

What the heck am I doing wrong? I also tried applying this class to the IMG tag but it produced the same result whereby the text is sitting under the image. I have searched high and low but can't seem to find the answer however I know I'm probably overlooking something simple.

Comment: put your codes on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Float the image, not the div container.

Comment: .img-float-left img {float: left}

Comment: If you don't close the quotes in an HTML tag, strange things can happen

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are using the `div` in your layout, you need to float the `img` within the floated `div` and keep the content of the `div` within the same block formatting context by using `overflow: auto`.

The result is that the `div` forms a self-contained block that contains the image and the
text, and the `div`, can then be floated left or right as needed in the layout.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 50%;
}
div img {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis velit ut neque tempor quis cursus tortor suscipit. Curabitur rutrum magna vitae arcu pharetra eget cursus ante accumsan. Nunc commodo malesuada adipiscing. Pellentesque consequat laoreet sagittis. Sed sit amet erat augue. Morbi consectetur, elit quis iaculis cursus, mauris nulla hendrerit augue, ut faucibus elit sapien vitae justo. In a ipsum malesuada nulla rutrum luctus. Donec a enim sapien. Sed ultrices ligula ac neque vulputate luctus. Suspendisse pretium pretium felis, in aliquet risus fringilla at. Nunc cursus sagittis commodo.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct to try to float the image instead of the parent div. 
Put the `img-float-left` class on the img instead.

The `img` tag also isn't closed, and the `src` attribute is missing a closing quote, but that may just be a copy/paste error. Would help to see your actual code.

Using just `float: left` on the img works fine given this example.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bwknkcw/)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are floating the `<div>` tag and it place the container of image( witch is `div` on the left side,not the image)
instead of floats you can use `align` for `<img>` tag. **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp)** is how to use it.and here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3z4fhrmr/4/)** that I create for you.

```
<div class='image-left'>
 <img src='http://placehold.it/100x100'/>
 text text text text text text text text text text text text  ...... 
</div>
```

css:

```
.image-left img {
 vertical-align:top
}
```